# Mysql phpmyadmin export/import column

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I follow this guide to export column

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486743/how-do-i-export-particular-column-in-mysql-using-phpmyadmin
```

my Sql table is :
ID , Name , description , url ,tag ,category_id .......................

So i want to export column `name` and to translate all names to different language
the problem is How to import column `name` back to same table but with changes ?
for examp :

```
Id =1 name = hello    after import -> Id =1 name = Здравей
Id =2 name = Bye      after import -> Id =2 name = чао
```

that i want to happen after the import .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LOAD DATA INFILE to bulk load the 800,000 rows of data into a temporary table, then use multiple-table UPDATE syntax to join your existing table to the temporary table and update the quantity values.

For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE your_temp_table LIKE your_table;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/your_file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_temp_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(id, product, sku, department, quantity); 

UPDATE your_table
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.id = your_table.id
SET your_table.quantity = your_temp_table.quantity;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE your_temp_table;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253773/4238757

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is create a temp table, import your modified info to it and update the first table joining the two. later on, delete the temp table.

Do something like this:

- Create a query to display only id and name fields from table1.
- Export the results to a sql file.
- Translate the names into Russian and save the file.
- Create a new table (like tmpTable) with two fields named the same as the ones you exported.
- Import the sql file into newly created tmpTable.
- Build the INSERT query joining the two tables,like:

UPDATE table1 JOIN tempTable ON table1.id = tempTable.id
SET table1.name = tempTable.name

Comment: ok but i dont see in to the import menu how can i navigate to import my file to table_x where is column `name`
if i understand you right

Comment: Were you able to export the columns you wanted to translate?

Comment: Create the appropiate query in phpMyAdmin, like SELECT id, name FROM table1. In the result page, go down and select export